# How to filter two columns in a csv?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

So I have a csv (https://ufile.io/y4nr9) which is seperated by ',' and contain columns such as: 'name','survived','sex' etc. I want to find the percentage of males that didnt survive and print the statistic. Here is my code so far:

```
import csv
reader = csv.reader(open('titanic-new_alphabetized.csv'), delimiter= ',')
filtered = filter(lambda p: 'male' == p[3], reader)
dict = []

input('press ENTER to exit')
```

Comment: so the first column(0s and 1s) is survived/not survived? is it?

Comment: What version of Python are you using? What do you expect to be in `dict` afterwards. You should never name variables the same as built-in types like that, by-the-way.

Comment: I am using python 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could filter them and compute the statistic like this in Python 3:

```
import csv

total, survived = 0, 0

with open('titanic-new_alphabetized.csv',  newline='') as csvfile:
    for row in filter(lambda p: 'male'==p[3], csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter= ',')):
        total += 1
        if int(row[0]):
            survived += 1

print('total: {}, survived: {} ({:.2f}%)'.format(total, survived, 
                                                 survived/total * 100))
```

Output:

```
total: 577, survived: 109 (18.89%)
```

Comment: Say now I want to find the percentage of people age 12 and below that didnt survive and then the average of all people that didnt survive, can I just change 'male' to '≤12' ==p[4]

Comment: Wait I am trying to find the percentage of males that DIDNT survive which are '0'.  Doesnt 'survived += 1' mean its searching for people that did survive?

Comment: csStudent: The lambda expression used for filtering requires a valid boolean expression, so to select folks 12 or under would require `12 <= int(p[4])` to be used. As for the survived vs died, surely you can figure out to how to change the logic to count the number of dead based on what's in my answer (or just subtract the number that survived from the total number).

Answer (score 0):

You are creating your dictionary using the `list` syntax.

You should use dict = {}

Answer (score 0):

You should also open the file as a variable, so you can close it easily later.

Or use `with ... as` to open files.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, remove the empty list first and then filter the list to get the percentage:

```
import csv

reader = csv.reader(open('1.csv'), delimiter=',')

data = filter(lambda p: p, list(reader)) # remove empty list
filtered=filter(lambda p: p[0]=='0' and p[3] == 'male', data)

print(len(filtered)*1.0/len(data))
```

Result

```
0.525252525253
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use csv.DictReader() to read your csv as a list of dict(here i have given the column names as c1,c2.. as I aint sure of their significance).

With that in hand, you can use list comprehension to iterate through the date and check for entries of male and get the survival date into list `men`

Now you can find the average of men who didnt survive(assuming '0' signifies dead and '1' for alive)

```
import csv
with open('names.csv') as file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(file, delimiter= ',',fieldnames=['c1','c2','c3','c4','c5','c6','c7'])
    #print reader # [{'c3': 'Abbing, Mr. Anthony', 'c2': '3', 'c1': '0', 'c7': '7.55', 'c6': 'C.A. 5547', 'c5': '42', 'c4': 'male'}, {'c3': '', 'c2': '', 'c1': '', 'c7': '', 'c6': '', 'c5': '', 'c4': ''}, {'c3': 'Abbott, Mr. Rossmore Edward', 'c2': '3', 'c1': '0', 'c7': '20.25', 'c6': 'C.A. 2673', 'c5': '16', 'c4': 'male'}...]
    men = [each['c1'] for each in reader if each['c4']=='male']
    #print men #['0', '0', '0', '0', '1'...]
    print men.count('0')*100/len(men)
input('press ENTER to exit')
```

Comment: the column names are : ['survived', 'pclass','name','sex','age','ticket','fare','cabin']  so does that mean I change men = [each['c1'] for each in reader if each['c4']=='male'] ===> men = [each['survived'] for each in reader if each['sex']=='male']

Comment: yeah and you need to change the fieldnames too!

Comment: If you dont mention the fieldnames the first row in your csv will be taken as column names. As far as i can infer, your input file doesnt have the column names as first row in your csv. Therefore you have to mention it explicitely!